# webview issues in vs code plugin

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I created webview based vscode plugin.
It's working fine in local vs code setup, but when I try with code server.
Webview did not work and getting error through servicewroker in google chrome.

Error loading webview: Error: Could not register service worker: SecurityError: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://135.249.146.94:8282/stable-74f6148eb9ea00507ec113ec51c489d6ffb4b771/static/out/vs/workbench/contrib/webview/browser/pre/') with script ('https://135.249.146.94:8282/stable-74f6148eb9ea00507ec113ec51c489d6ffb4b771/static/out/vs/workbench/contrib/webview/browser/pre/service-worker.js?v=4&vscode-resource-base-authority=vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net&remoteAuthority=135.249.146.94:8282'): An SSL certificate error occurred when fetching the script..

I try to add certificates for that even i also try to clean the cache but it won't work.

Start chrome like this --> chrome.exe  --ignore-certificate-errors --unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure=https://135.249.146.83:8282 --user-data-dir=C:\tmp

I also try this one so after that it works well but no user do this kind of things.

Is there any generic way for that.